# category to binary response variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert my category to binary response variable.

```
y.sample(5)
```

Output:

```
7325944    Not Liable
6817854        Liable
7401930        Liable
1324151    Not Liable
3747135        Liable
Name: hearing_disposition, dtype: object
```

```
def convert_to_binary(x):
    if x=='Liable':
        return 0
    if x=='Not Liable':
        return 1

y['hearing_disposition'] = y['hearing_disposition'].apply(convert_to_binary)
```

After running this I got:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-c867b2f7a6b8> in <module>()
      5         return 1
      6 
----> 7 y['hearing_disposition'] = y['hearing_disposition'].apply(convert_to_binary)
```

I was wondering if you could give me some hints to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use boolean mask and cast to interger:

```
y['hearing_disposition'] = y['hearing_disposition'].eq('Not Liable').astype(int)
```

**EDIT**

The solution above is for a dataframe `y` having the column `hearing_disposition`, if `y` is a Serie then:

```
y = y.eq('Not Liable').astype(int)
```

Comment: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-1f159c68d49b> in <module>()
----> 1 y['hearing_disposition'] = (y['hearing_disposition'] == 'Not Liable').astype(int)

Comment: Check the second solution as you have `y` as serie and not a dataframe.

Comment: Still got  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-1f159c68d49b> in <module>()
----> 1 y['hearing_disposition'] = (y['hearing_disposition'] == 'Not Liable').astype(int)

Comment: Right, because `y` is not a dataframe, `hearing_disposition` is the name of the serie, so use the second solution.

Comment: Awesome, mark the question as solved so it is trackable anymore, glad to hear that it worked.

Comment: Another quick question.  Not liable is 1 or 0? It's a big data set. Hard to find out!

Comment: Not liable is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_to_binary(x):
   if x=='Liable':
      return 0
   if x=='Not Liable':
      return 1

y=y.transform(lambda value: convert_to_binary(value))
```

Explanation: transform() can also be used without giving any keys (like you have mentioned while applying apply()) as 'y' is a Series. This should work out!! Also you can use sklearn LabelEncoder(). You can find it here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html